# Is there a glossary of QA / CIT?

Tags: qa-process

Do you know online glossaries where I could find definitions, but also "points of views" of experienced people, regarding trivial terms like:

- tear down / set up
- some keyword choices like "not ok" /vs/ "K.O." /vs/ "fail"
- red test / green

Something where I could validate the domain of QA when I doubt.

So, is there a glossary of the QA domain?

Comment: Check the following links and edit your question accordingly: [https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask] [https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask]

Comment: I get 404 pages on this links. Ok, should remove trailing ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of online glossaries available that provide definitions and expert perspectives on terms used in the software quality assurance (QA) and continuous integration/continuous testing (CI/CT) fields. Here are a few popular options (but I'm not sure if they cover the specific terms you are looking for):

1. The Official ISTQB Glossary: This glossary, published by the International Software Testing Qualifications Board (ISTQB), provides an official set of definitions for terms commonly used in the software testing industry. You can find it here: https://www.istqb.org/glossary-of-terms.html
2. The QA Glossary by TechBeacon: TechBeacon provides a comprehensive glossary of terms used in the QA and testing domains, along with perspectives from industry experts. You can find it here: https://techbeacon.com/qa-glossary
3. The Agile Testing Glossary by Agile Alliance: This glossary, from the Agile Alliance, provides definitions for terms used in the agile testing process, including technical and non-technical terms. You can find it here: https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/
4. The DevOps Glossary by DevOps Institute: The DevOps Institute's glossary provides definitions for common terms used in the DevOps and continuous delivery/deployment (CD) fields, including terms related to QA and testing. You can find it here: https://devopsinstitute.com/resources/glossary/

These glossaries are a great resource for anyone looking to validate their understanding of terms commonly used in the QA and CI/CT domains. They provide definitions, expert perspectives, and a helpful way to stay up-to-date on the latest industry language.

Answer (score -1):

There is this other Glossary from a private company.

https://infinum.com/handbook/qa/knowledge/qa-glossary - *the Infinum QA Handbook*

Samples:

> Exploratory testing - means testing with existing experience and knowledge of the mobile app or website. This insight gives the QA tester the ability to have a focused engagement without following formal test cases. Or in other words, testing the whole app without any specific plan or without using test cases.
>
> Selenium - probably the most popular web automation framework built on top of WebDriver (as many others are).
>
> User stories - an informal, general explanation of a software feature written from the perspective of the end user or customer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).